# Can I run a node.js server on a VPS but broadcast events to it from a go daddy hosted laravel backend?

Tags: node.js, laravel, sockets, socket.io, hosting

I have an app with a backend currently hosted on godaddy. The backend is Laravel 5.4 and the front end is Ionic 2. I want to add a live chat to the existing app. I will use socket.io and redis. All of the chat messages will be saved to my database (on godaddy). Go daddy doesn't allow running a node server unless you buy a vps but they charge too much

I was wondering if this setup is possible.

- A user sends a message
- The message is sent via a POST request from my frontend to my backend to be saved in the database.
- Once the message is saved, a broadcast message/event is sent from laravel to the frontend

Now my question is can I use something like A2 hosting ($5 for a vps) to ONLY host my socket.io & redis server. So basically I want to know will I be able to broadcast messages from laravel (go daddy) to A2 hosting, and have my frontend listening to the A2 server? Or do I have to host my whole backend on A2 hosting because I can't broadcast messages to A2 hosting unless a server is also running on go daddy

Hopefully what I'm asking makes sense

My server.js file (in laravel root)

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');

var redis = new Redis();
redis.psubscribe('private-chat.*', function(err, count) {
    console.log('psubscribe');
});

redis.on('pmessage', function(subscribed, channel, message) {
    console.log('pmessage', subscribed, channel, message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});
```

Sending the broadcast

```
// save it to the database and than 
event(new NewMessagePosted($message));
```

Broadcasting to the channel

```
public function broadcastOn()
{

    return new PrivateChannel('chat.'. $this->message->chatID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, then you want to know if you must host everything on A2 in order for your chat application to work. The answer is no. I have a node socket server running on its own that emits messages to several applications hosted on DigitalOcean, AWS and Heroku. As long as everything is setup and secure and each socket client is listening for the correct events from the remote socket server, I don't see the issue.

Comment: Yes thats correct I want to know if i can separate the chat and backend hosting because I don't want to move everything over. After a user sends a message, its saved in the database, and a broadcast event is emitted from laravel to a private channel that the frontend is listening to it. I'm just confused how I would connect to the server from the backend to broadcast.

Comment: hey, @derrickrozay you have any solution about your question?